# Limits of functions of 3 variables(not to sure what topic is this)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the limits or show that they do not exist:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to 0} \frac{xy+xz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

Can anyone lend me a hand and teach me how to do this. I am totally at loss at this. :(

Comment: Presumably this is multivariable calculus *and* homework. :)

Comment: Hint: When the degree of the numerator and degree of the denominator are equal, you should think about what happens along different lines through the origin.

Comment: yes, i need to practice limits of functions of several variables and i came accros this question. do you know how to do?

Comment: When the degree of the numerator and degree of the denominator are equal, their limits is 1?

Comment: Don't just guess. Try different lines. What happens along $x=y=z$? What happens along $x=z=0$, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
Let 
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{xy+xz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

then calculate
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0,0)\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to0}f(x,x,0)$$
what do you can conclude?

Comment: lim x→0 f(x,0,0) = 0

lim x→0 f(x,x,0) = 1/2

since the limits are not the same, so the limit does not exist?

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: is that how u apply to all limits of function  of 3 variables to get their limits?

Comment: We use this method to show that the function hasn't a limit, but in the case when the function has a limit we prove this not give a counterexample.

Comment: Do you know any examples of limits of function as (x,y,z) to (0,0,0)?

Comment: can you give me hint? well i found that limx→0f(x,0,0) and limx→0f(x,x,0) = 1/x. Thus, this tells me there's a limit. But i know if plug x=0 to 1/x, it'll be undefined.....

Comment: I forgot the exponent $3$ so my question is to find that $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{(x+y+z)^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=0 $ and I give you this hint: use the inequality $x\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: How do you use the inequality here? I couldn't show the limit = 0.

Comment: From your hint how to show the limit doesn't exist, i got limx→0f(x,0,0) = x and limx→0f(x,x,0)=4x.. does that mean the limit of the function does not exist?

Comment: I gave the hint to prove that the limit exists and to do this: since $|x|\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and we have the same inequalities for $y$ and $z$ then we find $$|\frac{(x+y+z)^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}|\leq 27(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}\to 0$$

Comment: Can you expand your working? How do you get 27(x2+y2+z2)1/2?

Comment: We have $(x+y+z)^3\leq (|x|+|y|+|z|)^3\leq (3\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3=27(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3$ then divide by ${x^2+y^2+z^2}$ to find the result.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x,y,z)\to0$ means $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to0$. Introducing (geographical) spherical coordinates $\phi$, $\theta$ we have
$$x=r\cos\phi\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\phi\cos\theta,\quad z=r\sin\theta$$
and therefore
$${xy+xz\over x^2+y^2+z^2}=\cos\phi\cos\theta(\sin\phi\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\ .$$
This shows that the given expression is totally independent of $r>0$ and only depends on $\phi$ and $\theta$, i.e., on the "shadow" of the point $(x,y,z)$ on the unit sphere $S^2$. Since for all $\epsilon >0$ the "shadows" of points $(x,y,z)$  with $r<\epsilon$ still fill the full sphere the requested limit cannot exist.